# How to inject dependencies when resolving a service form WindsorContainer?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Here's my scenario:
I have a ISampleProvider interface:

```
public interface ISampleProvider<TEntity>
{
TEntity Entity{get;}
}
```

and here's an implementation for this interface:

```
public class SampleProvider<TEntity>:ISampleProvider<TEntity>
{
public SampleProvider(TEntity entity)
{
Entity=entity;
}
public TEntity Entity
{
get;private set;
}
}
```

I'd like to inject an entity into SampleProvider when I resolve it from WindsorContainer
So I wrote this:

```
var container=new WindsorContainer();
container.AddComponent("smaple_provider",typeof(ISampleProvider<Person>),typeof(SampleProvider<Person>));
var arguments=new Hashtable{{"entity",new Person()}};
var sampleProvider=container.Resolve<ISampleProvider<Person>>(arguments);
```

But it's not working and a dependency resolver exception is thrown that says "Cycle detected in configuration "

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Windsor 2.0 ...
This test works fine for me:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleProviderTests {
    public interface ISampleProvider<TEntity> {
        TEntity Entity { get; }
    }

    public class SampleProvider<TEntity> : ISampleProvider<TEntity> {
        public SampleProvider(TEntity entity) {
            Entity = entity;
        }

        public TEntity Entity { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Person {}

    [Test]
    public void test() {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddComponent("smaple_provider", typeof(ISampleProvider<Person>), typeof(SampleProvider<Person>));
        var arguments = new Hashtable { { "entity", new Person() } };
        var sampleProvider = container.Resolve<ISampleProvider<Person>>(arguments);            
    }
}
```